# React Router ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up a React App and I'm getting the React Router ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS errors. I'm not sure what is going wrong here since I only have one page (please see the code below). I have tried rendering only a `paragraph tag` into the web but the error still keeps showing up (so I'm assuming is something with React Router rather than the jsx itself)

Any help will be highly appreciated it. This is my code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CSSReset } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import PageOne from '../pages/page-one.mdx';



export const MDXRoutes = () => (
  <Router>
    <CSSReset />
    <Switch>
     <Route path="/"}
      <PageOne />
     </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

PageOne code:

```
<Flex gridArea="edge" gridRow="1" justify="center" align="center" ml={6} as="header">
  <Text>This is a text for the Home Page testing</Text>
</Flex>
```

Thanks so much in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ48f.png)

Comment: What is `Routes` from React-Router? It should be just `Route`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { CSSReset } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import PageOne from '../pages/page-one.mdx';



export const MDXRoutes = () => (
  <Router>
    <CSSReset />
    <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <PageOne />
          </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried that but still the same issue...